# Is there a way to disable kerning of punctuation marks globally?

Tags: fonts, bibliographies, punctuation, microtype, kerning

I use the font `XCharter` in my document. Unfortunately, I get undesired kerning of punctuation marks following capital letters like W, P and T – especially in the bibliography (biblatex).

Is there a way to disable the kerning of punctuation marks globally (or in the bibliography)?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{XCharter}

\begin{document}

Smith, W., Anderson, P.

Smith, W{}., Anderson, P{}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: That looks like a problem in the kerning table for that particular font. Might be an idea to email the developer/maintainer. `\textit{y.}` also look rather tight. AFAIK it is not something that you can configure in the preamble (perhaps with XeLaTeX + fontspec).

Comment: I agree this should be reported. `charter` doesn't have this bug, for example.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `microtype`. Well, you should obviously use this anyway, in most cases, but you could also use it to increase the spacing around punctuation.

However, I don't think you can alter kerning *pairs* this way - all you can do is add kerning before or after every occurrence of a particular character. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{XCharter}
\usepackage[kerning]{microtype}
\SetExtraKerning
[ name = xcharterextrakerning,
  unit = space ]
{ encoding = T1,
  family = XCharter-TLF,
}
{
. = {500, },
}

\begin{document}

  Smith, W., Anderson, P.?

  Smith, W{}., Anderson, P{}.

  But this will also affect punctuation following a lowercase letter.

\end{document}
```

[image: use and abuse of kerning]